# Reflecting Generic classes

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I think this is impossible but let's try:

Is it possible to write the routine analyzeArrayList()
in such way that it prints dimension of ArrayList
and the bottomtype of list.

The example code should print:

> Dimension = 2 and Bottom type = class java.lang.Float
>   Dimension = 3 and Bottom type = class java.lang.Integer

We suppose that the parameter s is always instance of ArrayList, 
not instance of some other type. Note that list may be empty but not null.

```
  void analyzeArrayList(Object s)
  {
    int dimension;
    String typeString;

    //<Some code here!>

    System.out.println("Dimension = "+dimension+" and Bottom type = "+typeString);
  }



  Object s = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();
  Object t = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();

  .
  . 
  analyzeArrayList(s);
  analyzeArrayList(t);
```

Comment for this:

It is funny that if you have a object with field

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>
```

then you can write the method

```
  void analyzeArrayList(Field s)
```

if you know that Field s represents ArrayList.

Comment: You could use recursion to get to the bottom, and then use `value.getClass()` to figure out the type.

Comment: @Knownasilya - Won't work if it's empty.  And I don't think it's possible if it's empty...

Comment: Not possible. List may be empty (or partly empty in inner levels) as I said.

Comment: type erasure makes it impossible.

Comment: I missed the part where it mentioned that it can be empty. Yeah, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Could you possibly extend ArrayList and then have two new fields for dimension and typeString in your extended class?  Don't know if this is for a public API or not but you could name the ArrayList subclass with your application name at the front ("YourAppArrayList")

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Java only considers generics at compile time. If you have a `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`, the compiler knows that the lists are from different types which make it capable of creating some type of type-safe environment on a per-instance basis. Because of type erasure, at runtime it is like both lists contain objects and are equivalent to each other.